# Usage of other/another

Tags: word-usage, articles

I am making a test where I am asked to add the missing words.

> You can buy this shirt and [...] one. Which [...] would you like?

I would have added *the other* and *other* thinking that the sentence is talking about buying two shirts and one more.

The correct answer is adding *another* and *other*, since the sentence is talking about buying two shirts: one sure and one to choose.

Can both the answers be correct, or I am completely wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding the question “Can both be answers”, it is true that the alternative answers both are *grammatical*, but (1) they have different meanings, and (2) I don't find either to be natural.

(1) The phrase “this shirt and the other one” refers to two *specific* shirts, namely “this shirt” and “the other one”.  By contrast, the phrase “this shirt and another one” refers to one specific shirt (“this shirt”) and some indeterminately specified shirt.

(2) Rather than “Which other would you like?” I would say  “Which other shirt would you like?” if I wanted to emphasize I was asking about a shirt other than “this shirt”, but if I were selling shirts in a store or helping to pick out shirts I'd instead say “Which one would you like?” while gesturing toward the other shirts.